# How can I use a php array in a mysql search query?

Tags: php, sql, search

I was going to use the scuttle solution on: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html for handling searches on my website.  I was wondering how I could take the search input from a user and turn it into a single query.

For instance, let's say a user inputted 'blue dogs' in their search query... How could I dynamically update the query to include ('blue', 'dogs') in union and intersection queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like:

```
$search_string = implode(',', $search_array);
```

Now in your query you can use the `IN` clause:

```
$query = "select * from table where field IN ('".$search_string."')";
```

Comment: -1: String parameters should be quoted, **all** values should be filtered through mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

The methods posted here are correct, just one little security addition: Don't forget to escape  the user inputted data, otherwise you're just one step away from SQL injections.
Or avoid the query and use prepared statements instead:
[PHPManual Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

for example your user input is "blue dogs", then on the page

```
$searchstring = "blue dogs"; // or fetch the input
$arr = explode(" ",$searchstring); //this is explode the text by every "space" character
```

you have the user inputed string in array $arr now, now use it in query like you usually do